# Why does a character in the value column have a c in front of it and how can i make it list all the values

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe

I'm trying to convert the rows of a data frame that I created so it shows in the under values as a character variable. However, when I do this r concatenate the variables rather than list them all.

[image]

```
set.seed(7)
train.rows <- sample(rownames(project.df), dim(project.df)[1]*0.4)
valid.rows <- sample(setdiff(rownames(project.df), train.rows),dim(project.df)[1]*0.35)
test.rows <- setdiff(rownames(project.df), union(train.rows, valid.rows))
train.data.1 <- project.df[train.rows, ]
valid.data.1 <- project.df[valid.rows, ]
test.data.1 <- project.df[test.rows, ]

project.df.2 <- subset(project.df, Purchase %in% c("1"))
valid.data.2 <- subset(valid.data.1, Purchase %in% c("1"))
train.data.2 <- subset(train.data.1, Purchase %in% c("1"))
values <- as.numeric(unlist(values))

train.rows.2 <- as.character(train.data.2)
test <- as.character(train.rows.2)
```

Comment: @algae I want them to appear under values similarly to train.rows

Comment: `object 'project.df' not found`

Comment: The picture you provided cannot be a data frame since the number of values in each column is not the same. Perhaps it is a list. Use R commands to provide information about your data, `str()` and `dput()`. If there are too many rows to post use `dput(head())` to post a reasonable number of rows.